# Linear Equation system - solve only solvable variables

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

If I have the SVD of a Matrix $A$, how do I solve the linear equation system $Ax=b$?

The problem is that if I e.g. has this linear equation system:

$-2y + z = 3$

$-4y + 2z = 6$

$x -2y + z = 4$

Then it's easy to see that $-2y + z = 3$ and therefore both $y$ and $z$ has infinitely many solutions, and that $x = 1$. However, how do deduce this from a general linear equation $Ax=b$? I'm sure it has to do with the SVD.

Note: I'm writing a Java program computing this so if you have any computational resources to point me at it would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe it is a naive or silly question, but I do not see why you say that $x = 1$.

Comment: Do your math once again, and bingo $x = 1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we have $Ax=b$, where $A=\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -2 & 1 \\
0 & -4 & 2 \\
1 & 2 & 1 \end{array} \right]$ and $b=\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
3   \\
6  \\
4\end{array} \right]$, but the top two rows of $A$ are linearly dependent, producing the same equiation twice, which is why of course, there are an infinite amount of solutions for $y,z$.

So our system can now be written as $Dx=C$, where $D=\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -4 & 2 \\
1 & -2 & 1 \\
 \end{array} \right]$, and $C=\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
6  \\
4  \\
  \end{array} \right]$.

Comment: Yes but how do I implement that?

Comment: My guess would be to choose some $z$  values, reducing it to a 2x2 system.

Comment: I solved it with Gauss elimination. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, Rouché–Capelli theorem could be useful.

It's not related to SVD, though. I think you can implement it using Gaussian elimination.

**Some useful links:**

- [Gaussian elimination in Java](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/95linear/GaussianElimination.java.html)
- [About Rouché–Capelli theorem](http://venus.unive.it/~tolotti/RoucheCapelli_GSEM.pdf) (pag 4.)

Comment: I have a hard time seeing how to implement it. I already have Gaussian elimination but as said, it needs something more to actually detect the variables with infinite solutions.

Comment: This is not about determining how many solutions are possible, as the Rouché-Capelli theorem does. This is about saying the solutions to the variables which doesn't have infinite solutions and identifying the ones which has.